# Photoshop - How place Rectangular Marquee Tool on specific position

Tags: photoshop

Edit - @mark Setchell's solution below works great

I am using a fixed size style rect marquee tool and I want to place it at a specific position to then select that area.

I can see in "Info" the position i'm in but being precise with the mouse is not that easy. I'm looking for a way to enter the px position.
[image]
Thank you for your help

Comment: Open the **Info** window to see the coordinates, then draw the marquee, then go to the **Select** menu, then **Transform Selection** and now use the mouse to nudge the selection around the screen - remember SHIFT+Keyboard Arrow will move by factor of 10.

Comment: Hi @mark Setchell this works great and is the best solution :)

Comment: Ooops, I meant *"use the **keyboard arrows**"* not the mouse!

Comment: [Graphic Design Stack Exchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) is probably a better place for non-coding questions

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Ruler (Ctrl/Cmd + R) draw the appropriate grid by dragging out lines and then use the selection tool. They will snap in place and should solve the problem

check the guide for ruler here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CqNqW0pOMh0

Comment: Hi @Dhananjai Pai I have added a line to test but I can't snap it to the png's specific position I need it as you suggest, in fact the line is a shape and when I select Move tool I don't see the line - I need to select line tool again, can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a path using shape/pen tool, place it at required position and finally convert it to selection. For more details: [Convert between paths and selection borders](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/photoshop/using/converting-paths-selection-borders.html)